# Не правильная работа animate jquery

Tags: jquery, css, анимация

Существует проблема анимирования объекта. У объекта изменяется его ширина с помощью

`$('.side').animate({width: '100%'}, 2000)`

Однако при срабатывании этого кода, данному блоку вначале задается ширина в 2000% и анимируется он с этого значения из за чего анимация не правильная.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из-за чего может быть вызвана данная проблема?

Comment: можно только догадыватся, добавьте [mcve] в вопрос, чтобы он был предметным

Answer (score 0):

Дело было в ошибке самого Jquery, после того как обновился на новую версию все стало впорядке